# F# / SIlverlight Binding to algebraic datatypes

Tags: silverlight, f#, algebraic-data-types

Given a data structure of:

```
type Candidate =  SalesRep of SalesRep | Analyst of Analyst

type ScorableCandidate = {
    candidate: Candidate ;
    mutable comments: string ;
    mutable score: int ;
}
```

and a data grid that wants to be able to display either of  the candidates, is it possible to bind (using the WPF binding) to the ScorableCandidate?

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="First Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding candidate.fname}" IsFilterable="False" Width="100"/>
```

I am thinking not, as the binding syntax would bneed to be able to deconstruct the type - which I don't think is possible.

Thx

T

Comment: I don't work with WPF to give a good answer, but small projects I've worked on have made use of customer TypeConvertors (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970913.aspx) to get the functionality you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that you shouldn't have any trouble accessing the `candidate` field of the record type (because record fields appear as standard .NET properties).

Regarding the discriminated union - I like the suggestion to use custom type convertors as Juliet suggests. Another simpler option would be to expose the `fname` field (which is shared by both `SalesRep` and `Analyst` if I understand your example correctly) as a property of the `Candidate` type:

```
type Candidate = 
  | SalesRep of SalesRep 
  | Analyst of Analyst 
  member x.Name = 
    match x with
    | SalesRep s -> s.fname
    | Analyst a -> a.fname
```

Then you should be able to use standard WPF binding syntax for binding to properties.

Comment: This came up again and I think this is the solution we are going with.  I didn't realize a discriminated Union could support members...